# htaccess rewrite url only with png,jpg extensions

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, file-type

stupid question

how can put:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]
```

into :

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?url=*.(jpe?g|png|bmp)&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]
```

rewrite url 
`http://site.com/folder/index.php?url=123.jpg&do=xxx`

to

`http://site.com/folder/123.jpg?do=xxx`

first rule can do this,but I need to prevent gif file

Comment: The second is not a valid rewrite rule, and the first will duplicate the query string.  What is it you are trying to rewrite? Post a sample input URL (from the browser's perspective) and the output URL it is written to.

Comment: (Urgency removed, as that's a surefire way to get your question closed)

Comment: why don't you explain exactly what you are aiming for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are looking to allow the browser to supply an image URL like `folder/123.jpg` (or .gif, .png, .bmp) to `index.php?url=123.jpg` and append the existing query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/([^.]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$ folder/index.php?url=$1.$2 [L,QSA]
```

The pattern `([^.]+)` captures everything up to the `.` into `$1`, and the extension is captured into `$2`.  `[QSA]` will append the existing query string `do=xxx` without you having to do anything to append it manually.

This can be simplified in Apache2 with a non-capturing group `(?:)` so the whole thing is caught in `$1`.

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^.]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|bmp))$ folder/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or you could apply it conditionally:

```
# If the request ends in .jpg, .bmp, .png...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|bmp|png)$
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ folder/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```